# position of $\nabla$ (differential operator)

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, curl

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a constant vector and $\mathbf{r}=x\,\mathbf{i}+y\,\mathbf{j}+z\,\mathbf{k}$, verify the following identities:
>
> (i) $\nabla\cdot[(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathbf{A}]=2\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{A}$
>
> (ii) $\nabla\times[(\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathbf{A}]=2\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{A}$
>
> (iii) $\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{r})=0$
>
> (iv) $(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)\times\mathbf{r}=-2\mathbf{A}$.

in all these question when I use $\nabla$  with the constant vector $\mathbf{A}$ It should give me zero in all cases( div - grad - curl ) but when I come  in question [iv] the answer is $2\mathbf{A}$ by using the triple cross product not calculating  $\mathbf{A}\times\nabla  = 0 $.

Comment: $\mathbf{r}$ is not a constant vector, and the differential operator $(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)\times$ is acting on it.

Comment: A is the constant vector not r

Comment: No, $\nabla$ (or rather $(A\times\nabla)\times$) is acting on everything that comes after it, and in this case it is a nonconstant vector field $\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: shouldn't i use the determent to calculate Ax∇ first due to the brackets ?

Comment: Yes, and that give you a differential operator.

Comment: I think that's my problem here what's the meaning of differential operator and why It differs if It comes before or after the vector ? (sorry for my too many questions :'( )

Comment: @Omar, write the components of $A\times\nabla$  and you will see that it they are differrential operators, acting on the components of $\mathbf{r}$

Comment: if A = [c1 ,c2 ,c3 ] , ∇ = $ [ \frac{d}{dx} , \frac{d}{dy} , \frac{d}{dz} ]$

calculating the (i) component of the det. = $\frac{d}{dy} * c3 - \frac{d}{dz} * c2 $ = 0 - 0 = 0 ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manipulate differential operators as if they are constant.  In particular, you can't naively use the BAC-CAB identity because it switches the order around.

$\mathbf{A}\times\nabla$ is the vector-valued operator
$$
\mathbf{i}\left(A_y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-A_z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
+
\mathbf{j}\left(A_z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-A_x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
+
\mathbf{k}\left(A_x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-A_y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{A}=A_x\,\mathbf{i}+A_y\,\mathbf{j}+A_z\,\mathbf{k}$.  You take the cross product again with $\mathbf{r}$:
\begin{align*}
(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)\times\mathbf{r}
&=\mathbf{i}\left[(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_y\mathbf{r}_z-(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_z\mathbf{r}_y\right]\\
&\quad+\mathbf{j}\left[(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_z\mathbf{r}_x-(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_x\mathbf{r}_z\right]\\
&\quad+\mathbf{k}\left[(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_x\mathbf{r}_y-(\mathbf{A}\times\nabla)_y\mathbf{r}_x\right]\\
&=\mathbf{i}\left[\left(A_z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-A_x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)z-\left(A_x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-A_y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)y\right]
+\dots\\
&=-2A_x\,\mathbf{i}-2A_y\,\mathbf{j}-2A_z\,\mathbf{k}\\
&=-2\mathbf{A}.
\end{align*}